# How to place an overlay DIV with opacity < 1 over a Flash object

Tags: html, css, flash, opacity

We have a flash object and when we use blockUI or some other overlay div with opacity < 1, it doesn't make the flash area transparent. However, it do hides the flash object when opacity is 1, but I want to have the overly div transparent which make the flash area transparent too like it doing for other HTML objects.

Is it a know issue/thing? Any workaround?

Here is the code expert:

```
<object width="100%" height="200" align="" id="charts" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" wmode="transparent"> 
<param value="/charts.swf?library_path=/charts_library&amp;xml_source=/chart&amp;" name="movie"> 
<param value="high" name="quality"> 
<param value="#E6E6E6" name="bgcolor"> 
<param value="transparent" name="wmode"> 
<embed width="100%" height="200" align="" salign="TL" scale="noscale" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" swliveconnect="true" name="charts" bgcolor="#E6E6E6" quality="high" src="/charts.swf?library_path=/charts_library&amp;xml_source=/chart&amp;license="> 
</object>
```

For overlay div we are using jQuery.blockUI and FancyBox (when we need to some popup and block the UI). We also tried to overlay the flash object using a div with z-index. It overlays and hides the flash when opacity is 1 but not when it's < 1.

Here is the screen shot:

http://www.4shared.com/photo/PO-Cb1bi/Flash_Overlay_Transparency.html

Comment: Can you put up a link to your test?

Comment: shanethehat, sorry the live link is not ready yet. I can paste the code and a screen shot if you like.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the sample code.

Comment: Can you just upload and give a link to the full page please? You must be missing something and I'm sure any of us here could solve it really fast if you just posted the actual content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the wmode parameter of the flash object to "transparent".

//Article

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14201.html

//Video tutorial

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/524/cpsid_52418.html#flash

Comment: @Ascension, thanks for your comments. We already setting `wmode` parameter to `transparent`. It works fine when the opacity of overlay is 1. As we set the opacity < 1 say 0.8, it won't make the flash transparent. I have added sample code and screen shot in my question above.

Comment: I see you have the tag added to your object code but you must be doing it wrong somewhere. If you are using dreamweaver, you need to ensure that you have not selected an opaque background for the flash object, as you can define this with dreamweaver. Click on the flash object area and you will see an option to set the background color. Ensure you have not done this. Also read the article I've supplied and follow the video tutorial this is absolutely the way to do this do with all due respect if it's not working then you're missing something.

Comment: In both places? A quote from the link above: "Editing HTML code manually

To edit an existing HTML page, add the WMODE parameters to the HTML code.

Add the following parameter to the OBJECT tag: 
 <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> 
Add the following parameter to the EMBED tag:
 wmode="transparent" "

Comment: Yes, I have added in both places. Please check the code above. I copied it from my running application.

Comment: Oops... my bad, it was added in object as param and as attribute. Let me try with adding it to EMBED.

Comment: @Ascension, yes this was the problem. It's fixed now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the wmode transparent to your `<embed>` tag as well as the object:

```
<embed wmode="transparent" ...>
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: thanks for suggesting the correct answer. But I have accepted Ascension's answer considering the timestamp of posts. I think this makes sense. `+1` for your straight forward answer, though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this parameter in your flash object.

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

Here are the details: http://slightlymore.co.uk/flash-and-the-z-index-problem-solved/